# Android: Parse.com always retrieve me something in a getInBackground method, never get a ParseException != null

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I was testing my retrieving method for Parse.com, but I realized when I try to get an inexistent objectId, Parse.com never retrieve me a ParseException different to null and then I can't manage it.

The method in question is

```
public void QRDecodeResult(IntentResult scanResult, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (scanResult != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Data");
        query.getInBackground(contents, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done (ParseObject object, ParseException e){
                if (e == null) {
                     //Got it successfully
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "retrieved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }
        });

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //If the scan is cancelled then display a notification
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.noinput), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

When the objectId exists, everything is ok and I get the right info. But When I try with an inexistent objectId e==null too and then, I can not manage it.

The logcat doesn't show anything at all :S

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getInBackground() just use  getFirstInBackground() let me know if it solves the error

and i dont understand this part is it a typo or... i think it should be like

```
 if(e == null) {
       //got it successfully
        }
```

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I have just edit it! thanks!
The getFirstInBackground() doesn't work too, in fact it is so weird, instead of return me nothing, it tries to show a toas empty... But I don't have any toast with an empty String...